What color temperature should I use for for my studio, office and monitor?
I'm in the process of setting up a home portrait studio. I also have a home office, in a different room, where I would edit and make prints. Right now I'm deciding on what type of lighting to use (I'm somewhat limited since it is a rental, but I'm looking at everything from getting a bunch of "smart" bulbs that I can all sync together in an app to just using some powerful COB mono lights as the primary light source.)
My question is, how important is it to ensure a consistent color temperature across both rooms and possibly even my monitor? I calibrate my monitor using a Spyder to AdobeRGB and it defaults to a 6500k temperature. Should I also try to use 6500k for all ambient lighting and flashes for consistency? 6500k is a little cool for every day use, would it make more sense to set everything to 5000k? Would there be an advantage in getting something variable and maybe use 5000k for every day, then 6500k for shooting and when I'm editing and printing?
Thanks in advance!

Selection of light fixtures, (lamps, lightbulbs) should be based on their CRI value (color rendition index). We are talking about the weather the lamp outputs the full viewable spectrum. A CRI of 100 outputs the full spectrum. You should shop for lamps that output a CRI of 90 or better. The CRI is often printed on the label of light bulbs and fixtures with lamps installed.
That being said, the human eye is remarkable in many ways. They have the ability to adapt to a wide range of illumination, both color and brightness.
This adaptation is unique for left and right eye. Please perform this experiment. Procure some colored filters. Colored cellophane wrapping paper works also. Place a red filter over one eye and look about at various objects. Now remove the filter, close one eye and look about. A few seconds later, swap the eye that is closed. This experiment shows you how powerful the eye/brain combination is to the various colors of ambient light.  Try different colored filters. The filtered eye has changed its white balance. It will return to match the unpatched eye in a half hour. The color change is the complementary (opposite) color of the filter. Red – Cyan   Green – Magenta   Blue – Yellow. On way, the eye secretes a dye, visible purple (rhodopsin) that bathes the retina with a reddish-purple fluid that changes the sensitivity of the various rod and cone cells.
What I am telling you is, the color of the ambient light is not as important as a high CRI.
On a lighter note: Pirates are often portrayed with an eyepatch. This eyewear purpose is not what you think.  Sailors prepared for their watch at night by placing a patch over one eye. This patched eye will dark adapt in an hour or so thus night vision out of this eye is maximized.
Kodak advises 5000K with a high CRI.

For the un-calibration of the eyes independently, can I spam a page I did some time ago? The Initial notes section: https://otake.com.mx/ColorCalibration/ You do not need a colored filter for this test :)

The filter adds pizazz -- don't foo-foo!

:) https://i.sstatic.net/n3jr2fPN.png

I have mixed feelings about this.
I have read a lot and still, I have not a definitive conclusion, because I can not find a piece to the puzzle. The pieces are:
I. D65 is the standard for viewing the white point on a monitor. (a, b) It looks better, not yellowish, we know the drill.
II. D50 is the standard for viewing a print in the graphic arts.
III. The recommendations are using they as they are. D65 and D50...
The part of the puzzle I do not quite understand is Why D50 is the standard for viewing prints?

I thought at one time that as tungsten lamps were the standard for viewing everything on an interior (very few people see a print in direct sunlight on a clear sky) the printed industry just did not want to change the standard.
But probably the reason is the same as why warm light is the preferred choice to choose light when we are in a cozy interior. Our living room, the bedroom, vs the cold lights we use in the bathroom or the kitchen.
In the kitchen, we need a more accurate viewing light, probably because we need to see the color of the food, so we can detect if something is wrong with it (the same in the bathroom).
But still, we want the comfort of the warm light when we have a printed photo. Is this even an evolutionary trait? The warm light of a fireplace in the cave vs cast blue sky for hunting?
So probably the standard in the industry expects that the vast majority of people will use a warm light.

On the other hand print paper is rarely pure white. They have a small yellowish tint, and in aging paper, the oxidation makes the yellowing more prevalent. And this would make the opposite case. Use the cold light to counter the yellow. But in reality, this is yellowing not a real factor.

Nowadays you can get viewing booths and lamps for both temperatures.
The specific question is if you need or want to compare a print side to side, which brings some more questions.
Is the monitor bright enough to have a similar luminescence as a viewing boot? Their intensity can be quite bright.
Or you probably need to have them separated on a different desk.
Do you have additional color management systems, like a colorimeter, so you do not rely only on moving the eyes side to side?

My conclusion 1 is to have a viewing boot or zone a bit separated from the computer with the warmer light, to match the expectations of the print standard to see the print independently in the cozy environment and leave the exact match to some calibrating device.
And the same applies to the environmental light of the room. I would not use cold light in the room.
For the flashes, it is not that important if you define the white balance before shooting.

But, my conclusion 2 is that if the workflow is a bit more "industrialized" if you are using continuous light on the photo shoot, where you have the product on a bright table, and the camera thedered to the computer, and you make prints immediately, yes probably, to minimize eye adjustments, the viewing boot or zone could be D65 or a similar temperature as the video lights.

And I agree with Alan Marcus, a high CRI would be more important than a changing light condition. And you do not want to change light conditions, on the contrary, you need consistency.
a. Why calibrate monitor to D65 when light booth is D50?
b. Monitor calibration D65 white point soft proofing
c. What is D50 for graphic arts printing?

7500K (D75) Color North Sky Daylight
6500K (D65) Moderate to Deep Blue Average Daylight
5000K (D50) Moderate Blue Noon Sky Daylight

D50 is the standard for viewing prints because it is average daylight. In other words, D50 lighting (which is NOT exactly 5000K because there is a slight adjustment away from the black body radiator axis on the magenta←→green axis as well) is meant to replicate viewing the photo outdoors on an average day with the sun high in the sky.

Tungsten is around 2800K, nowhere near D50.

It also at used to be that the native whitepoint on monitors was something horrendous like 9200k.  This has probably improved with LCDs backed by white LEDs, but even then those LEDs are natively blue. A D65 is going to require less whitepoint adjustment, possibly reducing banding in pathological cases.

What the answers so far are missing or glossing over in my book is reasoning for CRI and white balances.
The human eye has three kinds of receptors which have different sensitivity curves regarding their sensitivity to light of different wavelengths.  Color in the world does not come in RGB or CMY but in a continuous spectrum of wavelengths.  Three-channel color information is catering to human vision, not to color in the world.
What a photographic filter held before your eyes does when looking at a rainbow is quite different from what it does when looking at a color picture of a rainbow.  The picture is composed essentially from 3 pigments intended to have certain effects on your vision under typical lighting.  The rainbow is composed from a continuum of wavelengths.  A filter may cut off the rainbow somewhere in the middle of greenish colors, but it cannot do the same with a picture of a rainbow.
The monitor is calibrated to have a similar effect on your eyes as objects reduced to RGB under particular lighting.  It makes sense to have the room lit by light having similar effect on your eyes.  But all that the viewing room needs to care about is the 3 color channels of your eye, a balance typically described with "color temperature" (which is actually not a sufficient specification for anything but incandescent light sources).
For the studio lighting, the colors in question do not come directly from light sources, but from light reflected from your subjects.  Here the continuity of the spectrum is important for a good color rendition.  This is usually expressed in the form of a CRI that describes how close the whole spectrum (and not just its direct perception by the human eye) of emitted light matches that from an incandescent light source of the respective temperature.
Exacerbating the color universe is that there is not just a continuous reflection/absorption spectrum based on wavelength, but that pigments may also emit light at different wavelengths than received (fluorescence) and studio lights are not intended to model that.  So the brightness of fabric treated with optical brighteners (ubiquitous detergent additives emitting visible light under UV radiation) will differ between daylight and studio light anyway.
All this means that you'll want to get a good CRI in your studio while that is not of similar importance with your monitor and viewing room.  You'll want to calibrate your monitor to have a certain response with your eyes corresponding to the lighting in your room.  If you do this calibration visually with a chart (which needs to be original, not a print), then the calibration procedure also benefits from being done under light with good CRI.

The color of lighting when shooting does not have to be the same as the color temperature and white balance to which your monitor is calibrated. The critical factor is to have the raw convertor set to the same white balance setting as the full spectrum (i.e. high CRI) light you used to illuminate your subject, assuming you want the subject to appear the same color as your eyes saw it when you shot it.
It's much more important for your light sources to have a high Color Rendering Index (CRI) than for them to be any particular temperature and tint.
On the other end of the question, it's important for your monitor's WB to match the ambient lighting in which you're working. Most graphics professionals use D65, but if you're operating in a home environment where the ambient lighting is probably closer to D50 or an even lower color temperature, then you can't really trust your eyes to perceive the colors of your monitor's output very accurately if it's set to D65.
In my own situation, I use D55 because it comes closer to matching the ambient lighting I have (5000K LED lighting) but not being so far away from D65 that my images look too cool when viewed on mobile devices, most of which output somewhere around D65. I also test actual white/light gray objects in my images by hovering the cursor over them in a photo and seeing what the RGB values for those pixels are. I adjust the color temperature and white balance until they're all equal as my starting point before adjusting further for any particular "mood" I want the image to have.
Keep in mind that D65 is not the same as "pure" 6500K such as would be emitted by a black body radiator with a surface temperature of 6500K. There's a slight tint adjustment in the green direction. Ditto for D55, D50, etc. This is because daylight, as measured at the surface of the earth when the sun is high overhead in a mostly clear sky has the same slightly green tint at around 5200K compared to a black body radiator with a surface temperature of 5200K with no atmosphere between it and the viewer. White balance is the combination of color temperature along the black body locus and tint along the green←→magenta axis which is roughly orthogonal to the black body locus.

The curved line is the black body locus
